# Preloader icon is not hidden when I disabled javascript from browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Coding for preloader icon is using HTML, CSS, and Javascript, but it's not hidden when I disabled the javascript from the browser console, because google will disable the javascript and CSS when it crawls to indexing the page. is there any other solution to use the preloader without javascript and CSS? Please help me.

my Html:

```
<div id="loader-wrapper">
            <div id="loader">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#loader-wrapper {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 999999;
background: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
}
#loader {
width: 90px;
height: 65px;
position: relative;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#loader ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
width: 90px;
    width: 90px;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
height: 10px;
}
#loader ul li {
position: absolute;
width: 2px;
height: 0;
background-color: #f1582a;
bottom: 0;
}
@keyframes sequence1 {
0% {
height: 10px;
}
50% {
height: 50px;
}
100% {
height: 10px;
}
}
@keyframes sequence2 {
0% {
height: 20px;
}
50% {
height: 65px;
}
100% {
height: 20px;
}
}
#loader li:nth-child(1) {
left: 0;
animation: sequence1 1s ease infinite 0;
}
#loader li:nth-child(2) {
left: 15px;
animation: sequence2 1s ease infinite 0.1s;
}
#loader li:nth-child(3) {
left: 30px;
animation: sequence1 1s ease-in-out infinite 0.2s;
}
#loader li:nth-child(4) {
left: 45px;
animation: sequence2 1s ease-in infinite 0.3s;
}
#loader li:nth-child(5) {
left: 60px;
animation: sequence1 1s ease-in-out infinite 0.4s;
}
#loader li:nth-child(6) {
left: 75px;
animation: sequence2 1s ease infinite 0.5s;
}
```

JS:

```
    function prealoader () {
if ($('#loader').length) {
  $('#loader').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
  $('#loader-wrapper').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
  $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
};
}
```

Comment: Google a does not ignore css, so if you hide something initially with css, it then should imho not appear in the google Index.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an animated SVG icon that animates.